# Passing a path as a parameter in Pentaho

Tags: parameter-passing, pentaho, transformation, jobs, kettle

In a Job I am checking if the file that I want to read is available or not. If this csv exists I want to read the data and save them in a database table within a transformation.

This is what I have done so far:
1) I have create the job, 2) I have implemented some parameters, one of them with the path for the file, 3) I have indicated that I am going to pass this value to the transformation.

[image]

Now, the thing is, I am sure this is should be something very simple to implement, but even when I have follow some blogs, I have not succeeded with this part of the process. I've tried to follow this example:

http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com.co/2011/03/pentaho-data-integration-scheduling-and.html

My question remains the same. How can I indicate to the transformation that it has to use the parameter that I am given him from the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just mixed up the columns

- Parameter should be the name of the parameter in the transformation you are running.
- Value is the value you are passing.

Since you are passing a variable, and not a constant value you use the `${}` syntax to indicate this.

[image: Screenshot of Transformation settings]

Comment: You are the guy. Thanks for you precise explanation!!